# Generating Java cssSelector to click span element in Selenium

Tags: java, css, selenium, path, html

I'm calling IE driver to launch this webpage (Business Objects). I'm able to login with the credentials. I need to click on a  element on the next page. Need help writing the java to read this element and click.

```
<span style="white-space:nowrap;" class="iconText" id="IconImg_Txt_btnListing">Document List</span>
```

This is what I got so far using firebug-firepath.

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
pickObj = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#IconImg_Txt_btnListing"));
pickObj.click();
```

Update: Another attempt-

```
    public class InitComp {

//private WebDriver driver;

@FindBy(how = How.CSS, using = "#IconImg_Txt_btnListing") private WebElement       DocListBtn;


public void clickDocList() {
    DocListBtn.click();
}

}
```

This class is called as-

```
InitComp init = new InitComp();
PageFactory.initElements(driver, init);
init.clickDocList();
```

This does not help either though. Throws me an exception - "ElementNotFound". This page happens to be the first page after login. Where am I going wrong?

Thanks.
Arya

Comment: Your code looks all right to me... What is the problem?

Comment: There is an id for the element. Any specific reason for css selector. You can also try xpath //span[text() = 'Document List']

Comment: Try `By.id("IconImg_Txt_btnListing")` - not sure if this will help but it's definitely cleaner

Comment: Thanks for updates. "By.id" din't work either. I also tried @FindBy with CSS. Pasting the code in an update.

Comment: are u using any kind of wait before finding elements?

Comment: No sir. Thankfully I was able to come to a solution. I was switching to an incorrect frame and hence my element would never get detected by any means. Thanks to all once again.